# RSS Feed for Searches?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, search, feed

Is it possible to get an RSS Feed for search queries? Sometimes the tags are not enough. For some topics the tags are not sufficient or you need to follow multiple tags and Search just simplifies this gap however the search results don't have an RSS feed or at least I can't seem to find. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Searches are too performance intensive to be RSS feeds.

If you can't express your search as a set of tags ([we support and/or in tags, see the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/)), which *does* have an RSS feed, I humbly submit you aren't trying hard enough. :)

Comment: Ok I quite like the look of this. Is there a way to look for "Visual-Studio" And ("Plugin" Or "Addin" Or "Extensibility")

Comment: ok looks like the best way to do this is "addin visual-studio OR plugin visual-studio OR DXCore visual-studio OR visual-studio-addins"

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Jeff. I would up vote but I'm a little light on this site :(

Comment: Seems I can't accept either.. Strange given that I asked the question and although declined.. your answer is still the best.

Comment: what? you didn't ask this question, Cem Catikkas did. He has to accept.

Comment: Doh! You're totally right :) Forgot that I'd linked to it from my question, which was a duplicate :) Note to self: Get more sleep :)

Comment: Tags don't exist for everything, nor should they.  One example I have right now is "PDB".  There is currently no PDB tag, but I'm interested in questions that contain PDB.  I don't have the rep to create the tag, but even if I did, I don't think every single esoteric topic that deserves a "saved search" deserves a tag.  I do want RSS feeds for all of my saved searches.

Comment: Time to beat a dead horse.  I provide a free JavaScript library and have found that some people prefer to post their questions/problems here instead of contacting me directly.  I would like to be able to keep up with questions about my library using an RSS search to find new posts containing the library name.  There is no tag for my library name so I can't subscribe that way.  It seems a search RSS is the best solution here!

Comment: Could this be reconsidered now that searches have been vastly improved?

Comment: Plus one for revisiting this, how about it @JeffAtwood?

Comment: I am in an identical situation to @AndrewM.AndrewsIII - I can find questions about my cordova plugin with this search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22cordova-plugin-app-version%22 but I have no way to stay updated when new ones come in. Should I add a tag for my plugin and hope people find it? Email alerts would be better than RSS feeds for me, but I can't find a way to set those up either.

Comment: This is a very unhelpful answer. There is no way that all relevant searches can be resolved by tags alone. This lack of flexibility is really hurting the communities ability to respond to relevant questions.

Answer (score 15):

I have to agree with Cem. It would be really handy to have RSS feeds for searches, even if the feeds were based on "cached" results. In my case, I'd like to be able to find all questions on SO that have specific keywords so I can provide targeted help, and in many cases people don't (or forget to) add the keywords as tags.

I know it would be difficult to figure-out an effective caching strategy for searches (since any collection of terms would in theory generate another set of cachable results), but I'm sure the geniuses at SO can figure it out, right? :)

Answer (score 3):

**Of course you can** : use a service like [feed43.com](http://www.feed43.com/) and create the RSS feeds you need by yourself for any website.

For example, I've created an RSS feed for all new python accepted answers :

http://www.feed43.com/python_new_accepted_answers.xml

It corresponds to this search :

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[python]%20hasaccepted%3a1

Comment: Please share your Global Search Pattern and Item (repeatable) Search Pattern

Comment: I second this. Or put your idea/answer into a separate thread and link here?

Comment: No longer works because of Stack's captcha.

Answer (score 2):

I am following up on the comment of Jérôme Radix in this thread. Unfortunately, his comment has a now invalid link and doesn't show how to set up this custom RSS feed, so I'm showcasing it here.

1. Perform the search you want to use 
   [image]
2. Copy the search-URL from your browser

   [image]
3. Go to the site [Feed43](http://www.feed43.com)
4. And use the link 'Create your own feed'
   [image]
5. *Read* and accept the conditions for use.
6. Enter the search-URL as a starting point. Press Reload and (hopefully) get the source of your search page.

   [image]
7. Now comes the 'tricky' part: Find the templates which give you the text snippets you want. For me, I used

   `<div class="search-results">{%}</table>`

   as global search pattern and

   `<div class="summary">{%}<a href="{%}" title="{%}">{%}</a>{%}<div class="excerpt">{%}`

   as Item (repeatable) search pattern. Pressing extract then gives me the following results:

   [image]
   As you can see, for each item, the extracted snippets `{%2}` and `{%4}` are useful, the others are the 'junk' in between.
8. In the last step, I use these two snippets to define me the Title and the link in my RSS feed. (I keep the feed title, link and description as the defaults are reasonable.)
   [image]

   Using the preview shows me my custom RSS feed and the final RSS feed URL:
   [image]

Comment: No longer seems to work since the captcha gets in the way