# Save search terms and be notify if/when searches result in new "hits"/questions

Tags: feature-request, search-subscription

The favorites updates are nice, but I would also like to save search terms and be notified of additional questions that match the stored search criteria.

Specifically this is for a small set of questions on SO - I just don't want to have to manually search each week or month - I would like an event when a new question meets the criteria.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/rss-feed-for-searches