# Daily update of search results

Tags: feature-request, search, feed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RSS Feed for Searches?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/rss-feed-for-searches)

Is it possible to create an RSS feed for a given search?

I have a couple of projects that get mentioned on StackOverflow in connection with questions or bugs. But currently I have to search for the keywords because people don't tag them properly. It would be nice if I could search for the keywords and then save the search as an RSS feed, which would notify me of any activity related to my open source projects.

Comment: Could the API be used to periodically poll for this info, instead?

Comment: Jeff Atwood closed the other thread off by saying that maintaining such a feed would be too resource intensive. I could imagine a one off search and the an observer that monitors all subsequent postings and updates the RSS feed accordingly. I don't see that being that much of an overhead, especially since feeds can be shared.

Comment: For what it's worth, [Jeff has said that he doesn't think RSS has a very interesting or useful future](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106214/162705)

Comment: I appreciate that. But as I state in my comment above, I think he is wrong about the reason for his decision. The RSS feed would only have to query the system once and afterwards only updates. This should be less of a load than if I performed a full query every day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can easily be done with [Stack2RSS](http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com), a tool I wrote that converts data retrieved from the [public API](http://stackapps.com) into an RSS feed.

In your case, the feed looks something like this:

> `http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/` **`{site}`** `/search?intitle=` **`{search_terms}`**

Example that provides an RSS feed for questions that contain the tags [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql):
http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow.com/search?intitle=php+mysql

Comment: Will give this a try.