# Daily-digest emails based on search-profiles

Tags: feature-request, search, feed, email-notification

This post is correlated to my original question on [StackOverflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268700/whats-the-best-way-to-regularly-check-on-specific-topics/268702#268702) and a subsequent question there on [RSS functionality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268720/rss-feed-from-search-result-missing/268721#268721).

From the answers there I've learned that a feature for RSS of (fulltext) searches was [turned down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/rss-feed-for-searches) because of performance issues.

I understand this. However, a similar feature I would propose would be the following:

- In user-profiles any user can define favourite custom-searches
- These favourite "search-strings" can be quickly accessed when online for convenience
- More importantly: The user can specify that he wants to automatically receive a daily/weekly digest email of new entries appearing with this search since the last digest period.

This would be much less performance consuming than an RSS feed for any search a user has ever entered! The amount of performance cost can additionally be geared by allowing each user only a limited amount of such daily-digest searches.

I think such a feature would be absolutely great, as it allows people to 'silently' listen to exactly their needs.

Comment: This would be by default off and toggleable in the settings?

Comment: Yes, sounds reasonable. Although you don't need to turn something "off" which hasn't been created in a first place. i.e. the user has to _actively_ create the search in his profile. If he doesn't, there is no RSS/digest mail anyway.

Comment: Following up a suggestion by **Jérôme Radix** I have added a step-by-step solution using an external RSS feed compile side. See my answer in [RSS Feed for Searches?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/rss-feed-for-searches)