# Can I get an RSS feed of all questions with score at least 0?

Tags: feature-request, feed, score

On [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), most questions get closed, usually due to belonging on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) instead, and often, they don't belong even there due to being homework or being answered in every textbook on the subject.

I use Stack Exchange through RSS feeds, so what I want is an RSS feed that doesn't include such questions. Some of them are closed, some migrated, many are on hold, and some are just waiting to reach any of those statuses - but whatever their status, they will usually have a negative score.

So I feel the best way to exclude them is to have an RSS feed of all questions with a score of at least 0.  Of course the entries in this list won't always be accurate, as scores may change, but it would already a big improvement.

Can I define such an RSS feed on a Stack Exchange site right now?
If I can, how?
If not, how can I request this feature?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RSS Feed for Searches?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/rss-feed-for-searches)

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe: The linked question would certainly be capable of satisfying this, but it was declined for performance reasons that wouldn't necessarily apply to this more limited request, so I don't think they're really dupes.